# Why using gerund in "What *appearing* in the rest of the issue"

Tags: gerunds

Has the word **appearing** in the sentence below been used correctly? For example, should it not be "will appear"?

> As a prelude to this special issue, we decided to write an extended
>   editorial and briefly review the most important trends in application
>   of AM, thereby setting the stage for what **appearing** in the rest of
>   the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct as is. Possible options are:

- will appear
- what will be appearing
- what is going to be appearing
- what appears